# How to get specific key value in a json in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I´ve got a series of objects from aws texteract which I want to create a json of.

```
  '2': {
    '1': 'Total revenues ',
    '2': '1,243 ',
    '3': '1,283 ',
    '4': '1,137 ',
    '5': '1,351 ',
    '6': '1,926 '
  },
  '3': {
    '1': 'Personnel costs ',
    '2': '-724 ',
    '3': '-711 ',
    '4': '-633 ',
    '5': '-730 ',
    '6': '-994 '
  },
  '4': {
    '1': 'Non-personell costs ',
    '2': '-252 ',
    '3': '-262 ',
    '4': '-273 ',
    '5': '-282 ',
    '6': '-297 '
  },
  '5': {
    '1': 'Total operating costs ',
    '2': '-976 ',
    '3': '-972 ',
    '4': '-905 ',
    '5': '-1,012 ',
    '6': '-1,291 '
  }
```

Ive removed the first key '1' to only keep numbers.
As each key represents a year I want to loop through starting of key '2' in the first iteration and then key '3' and so on...
How would I do this?

```
for (const data in test) {
    if (Object.values(test[data]['1']).length != 0) {
        let column = test[data]['1'].replace(/\s+$/, '')
        headers.push({
            [column]: 1
        })
        delete test[data]['1'];
        // console.log(Object.keys(test[data][data]))
        let array = ['2','3','4','5','6']
        array.forEach(x => {
            console.log(data, test[data][x])

        })
}
```

Many of my tries ending up with that it iterates through keys 1 to 6 and then goes to next object and iterates through that

Comment: What about using `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Ive tried that, didnt do anything really than adding lots of quote signs :/

Comment: Quote signs? It turns an object into JSON (a string). If you don't want JSON what do you want?